# How to get Ubuntu in WSL 2 to talk to an HTTP server on same Windows host?

Tags: networking, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running a console app in Windows 10 which has a self-hosted HTTPS server listening on port 44340. It's an ASP.NET Core website (Kestrel) and its perfectly browsable on the Windows side.

I cannot reach this port from within a Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL2) console running Ubuntu 18.04, testing with `curl`.

I've tried adding a Windows Firewall rule for that port but it doesn't seem to work.

I've tried via `localhost`, as well as the two IPs I can see for my machine. One is the real NIC using DHCP and the other is a vEthernet adapter for WSL with a `172.31` address.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did.

- Disabled the Windows Firewall (then once proven working, re-enabled and added a rule).
- Add a hosts file entry on the Windows side for host `xyz` pointing at my physical NIC IP.
- Created a self-signed certificate for `xyz`.
- Configured Kestrel to listen on the physical NIC IP and load the certificate for `xyz`
- Checked the Windows side worked with Chrome.
- Launched WSL and pinged `xyz`.
- Ran `curl https://xyz:44340` and observed the failure to validate my self-signed cert.

That confirms TCP is working, so I'm off to bed. Essentially the blockers were:

- Firewall.
- Kestrel not listening on the right IP.

Answer (score 0):

See guidance here

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking#accessing-windows-networking-apps-from-linux-host-ip

> If you want to access a networking app running on Windows (for example an app running on a NodeJS or SQL server) from your Linux distribution (ie Ubuntu), then you need to use the IP address of your host machine. While this is not a common scenario, you can follow these steps to make it work.

> Obtain the IP address of your host machine by running this command from your Linux distribution: `cat /etc/resolv.conf`
> Copy the IP address following the term: nameserver.
> Connect to any Windows server using the copied IP address.
> The picture below shows an example of this by connecting to a Node.js server running in Windows via curl.

You will also need to allow inbound connections to that port in the host. (Through a firewall rule).